# Ajax file upload to Parse Express JS get 500 server error for files more than 2 MB size

Tags: parse-platform

I am getting 500 internal server error issue when uploding file having size more than 2MB to parse.com through an ajax.The application is hosted on parse.com and written using Cloud code plus Express JS. Files (images+videos) used to be
uploaded without any problem but recently application is getting 500 error for big files. Files less than 1 MB are still uploaded successfully. Let me show the code.

**1. Express JS controller to upload file (Server-Side)**

**Note1:**  Upload file is not send to url, *https://api.parse.com/1/files/filename* but to custom url created in
Express JS,  *https://example.com/file?name=filename*

**Note2:** File data is send to custom Express JS url and the controller method "file", mention below, make use of Cloud Code Buffer Module to create parse file and send response back to client(Browser).

```js
exports.file = function(req, res) {

  var buf = new Buffer(req.body, 'base64');
  var fileType = req.get("Content-Type");
  var fileName = decodeURIComponent(common.trim(req.query.name));

  var file = new Parse.File(fileName, {base64: buf.toString('base64')}, fileType);

  file.save().then(function() {

   res.json({url: file.url(), name: file.name()});

  }, function(error) {

    var message = "";
    if(req.app.settings._gs.debug === true) {
        message = error.code + ' - ' + error.message;
     }
      else {
        message = 'Failed uploading file.';
      }
    res.json(message);
  });

};
```

**2. Jquery ajax method (Client-Side)**

```js
//file change handler

$('.upload').on('change', function(e) {
  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  uploadVideo(files[0]);
});

//Video upload handler
var uploadVideo = function(file) {

  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "https://example.com/file?name=fileNameWithExtension",
    data: file, //file binary data
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
      //set content type
      jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      //success callback
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, exception) {
      //error callback
    }
  });

}
```

Code working absolutely fine with file less than 1 MB but more than 1MB size gives 500 internal server error.

I had tried to debug the problem and i found an interesting thing, which is, the control never reaches to controller method, controller does not execute "    exports.file = function(req, res) {....}" but breaks before at some point and send 500 error. There is no entry in parse.com log for an error. There is no way i can find the real problem which causes the 500 code. Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1):

Found out the problem. Parse.com does not allow more than 1MB of post data.